# Writing to a SUBSTed drive from NSIS installer

Tags: installation, nsis

I'm having problems writing to a SUBSTed drive from my NSIS installer.

```
IfFileExists  "K:\PROJECT\CFG\*.*" 0 DoesNotExist  
SetOutPath "K:\PROJECT\CFG"  
File ..\CFG\\*.*

DoesNotExist:
```

Moreover - it doesn't even find the path so I ended up commenting the IfFileExists command which then leads to the following error being generated.
I tried running the installer as admin but still I get the following message:

> Error opening file for writing:
>
> K:\PROJECT\CFG\CFG.x
>
> Click Abort to stop the installation, Retry to try again, or Ignore to
>   skip this file.

where K: is the SUBSTed drive.

If using the actual path it works fine.
Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to provide some details, e.g. the code segment of your script causing the error.

Comment: @idleberg Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the problem. It's the UAC elevation. The SUBSTed drive doesn't exist for the admin account and therefore won't be visible/accessible to the installer.